# Unable to create websocket connection

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc

I am new to WebRTC and WebSockets and was following [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_rtcpeerconnection_apis.htm) tutorial to create a WebRTC demo project, but I am unable to create a WebSocket connection. I have followed the same steps as mentioned in the project.

His project is running on port 8080 and he mentioned `ws://localhost:9090`. My project is running on port 8081, but I copied his URL `ws://localhost:9090` because I didn't know the significance of 9090 and I received this error and my server is node.js.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: If your server is running on port 8081, the websocket should connect to 8081.

Comment: @robertklep then I am getting handshake error

Comment: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Comment: Are you actually running a server yourself?

Comment: @robertklep yes. I have created a node.js server following tutorial of node.js from same site

Comment: Can you show us some code at this point (client / server).