# Unable to start node.js server using static command

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I am totally new to webrtc and nodejs. I was building a webrtc video calling app using webrtc tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_environment.htm but this is build using Linux mint os and I have windows OS. So I have downloaded nodejs zip and set its path in environment variables . I am able to run js file also but I am not able to start node.js server using static command as told in step 6. How to use this static command in windows.

Comment: Node.js works the same way in Windows and Linux. So i think the problem is not your OS. Any errors in the console?

Comment: I write static after navigating to the directory where html files resides.

Comment: I am receiving this error while running my html file on browser WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Comment: Without some code is hard to figure out what is happening. Correct port? Check the server implementation. There is a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627838/unable-to-create-websocket-connection) but it doesn't have an answer yet...

Comment: @SamuelMéndez That's why I have given the link of the tutorial I am following. The code is same as gievn in the tutorial

Comment: Where is the connection to the websocket? I cannot find it in that page, sorry.

Comment: @SamuelMéndez I has mentioned some points to start server and browse our html files on localhost